# Rails: Item is not removed from cart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cart

i am working on Order app with cart and line_items in it. Facing problem while deleting line_item in cart. On clicking remove item, nothing happens. Can anyone tell, where i am going wrong?
My cart.html.erb in orders

```
<% @order.line_items.each do |item| %>
      <%= link_to "remove item", item, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?",:remote => true %>
<% end %>
```

My orders controller have:

```
def cart
    @order = current_or_guest_user.orders.includes(:line_items=>[:product]).last
end
```

And i have defined delete item method in line_items controller:

```
 def destroy
             line_item.destroy
             redirect_to cart_orders_path
 end
```

Order model is:

```
belongs_to :user
attr_accessible :completed_at, :email, :item_total, :number, :payment_state, :payment_total, :special_instructions, :state, :total
has_many :line_items, :dependent => :destroy
```

Line item model is:

```
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :order
attr_accessible :price, :quantity, :product_id
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Do you have a `before_filter` in your `LineItemsController` pointing to a method which finds the line item? If so, pls post it.

Comment: @shioyama no, i dont have before_filter

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple inconsistencies in your code. For one, I don't know if you are simply missing a piece of your code, but you are not loading the line_item you want to delete:

```
def destroy
         @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
         @line_item.destroy
         redirect_to cart_orders_path
end
```

Secondly, you specify :remote => true on your destroy link, which turns on AJAX mode, but then you simply redirect in your destroy action.

Comment: Just interesting. Why instance variable? Will it be used somewhere else?

Comment: Not really, that's just me being stuck in scaffold conventions.

Comment: No working. log is saying this: NameError (undefined local variable or method line_item' for #<LineItemsController:0x988f820>): app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:7:in destroy'

Comment: Are you sure you are running the up to date code? Because that error is exactly what it should say with your version, and my answer doesn't even have a "local variable or method line_item" in it.

Comment: i was getting error of 'A server is already running. Check /var/www/mealnut/tmp/pids/server.pid' while running rails s on terminal. Then i ran bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -P tmp/pids/server2.pid. Is the error related to this? I am working on app since a month and it was fine till yesterday.

Comment: You don't stop rails server and try to run another on the same port. Stop your server and then start new. Do `sudo pkill ruby` if you can't find how to stop yor rails server.

Answer (score 0):

First find the object that you want to destroy

```
def destroy
  line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
  line_item.destroy
  redirect_to cart_orders_path
end
```

Comment: No working. log is saying this: NameError (undefined local variable or method `line_item' for #<LineItemsController:0x988f820>):
  app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:7:in `destroy'

Comment: it is mentioned in question text.

Comment: @user1957141 just for testing, run the destroy method only with `LineItem.find(params[:id]).destroy`  see what happens

Answer (score 0):

1. Do you have route for line_item.destroy? please show us your routes.
2. Do you call destroy method when you press "Remove item"? Do something like 
   `def destroy
     print "Line item destroy method called"
     line_item.destroy
     redirect_to cart_orders_path
   end`
    
   and then try to click "Delete item" link. Is string "Line item destroy method called" printed in your server logs?

Comment: My route is resources :orders do
   collection do
     post :add_to_cart
     get :cart
   end
 end
 resources :line_items. Log is showing this: NameError (undefined local variable or method `line_item' for #<LineItemsController:0x988f820>):
  app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb:7:in `destroy'